# JavaScript: The Good Parts - chapter 8, function.apply()

Tags: javascript, bind, apply

For the following code, based on page 84 of "JavaScript: The Good Parts", can someone explain why **[1]** and **[0]** are used? I understand that they're supplying the arguments **1** and **0** to slice, respectively, but what's the point of that?

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (that) { 
  var method = this;
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
  var args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]); // Why is [1] here?

  return function () { 
    return method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0]))); // Why is [0] here?
  };
};

var x = function () { 
  return this.value;
}.bind({ value: 666 }); 

console.log(x()); // Returns 666.
```

I believe I understand the big picture -  the function **x** has been designed to extract the value of the **value** property. We then bind an object that has a **value** property name/value pair and execute the **x** function. The **x** function reaches into the supplied object, as if it where a method of that object, and returns the value of the **value** property.

What I do not understand is how this is accomplished (I note Crockford's quasi-amusing use of **666**). Thanks in advance.

Comment: That just seems silly. If anything, I'd use `slice.call(arguments, 1)`. The point is to get all the arguments after the first (`0` index) into a new array

Comment: It's the same as the more common `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)`. If `arguments` were a real array then you could write `arguments.slice(1)`

Comment: If you're asking why there are brackets, that's because [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) takes the arguments to the function it is applying as an array. As @Ian notes, using call allows you to use arguments without wrapping them in an array.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument for apply needs to be an array, if [2] were 2 instead, this would happen

> Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 2);
>   Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

`arguments` is a baked in property which represents all of the arguments send to a function in an array like object. slicing this array will remove unwanted parts. In the case of bind, `that` is passed as an argument so slicing after 1 will remove that.

As a result

```
var args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]); // Why is [1] here?
```

Will take all of the extra arguments sent to bind, for example .bind({},1,2,3,4) will result in args being [1,2,3,4]

Next, a function is returned

```
return function () { 
 return method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0]))); // Why is [0] here?
};
```

`that` is going to be the new scope to use, `method` is the function that bind was originally called from, `args.concat` is going to take the previous array examined, and then add in all of the arguments which the method was called with, which is why `[0]` was used as opposed to `[1]` (where `that` was passed and was not being used as an argument for the method).

Answer (score 0):

`Function.prototype.apply()` takes 2 arguments, a value for `this` and an *array* of `arguments`. Even if there is only one argument, it expects an array.

So:

```
slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
```

is almost equivalent to:

```
arguments.slice(1);
```

I say almost because `arguments` is not a real array, and it does not have a slice method, which is why you have to do this the funky way.

As others note in the comments, you can use `call` instead to make this cleaner. `call` expects a value for this `this` and then any number of additional individual arguments. Which means you can instead do:

```
slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have some function, it doesn't matter what it does, and you are binding it to a context and passing some arguments in.

```
function myFunc(a, b, c) {

}.bind(myContext, arg1, arg2)
```

Now let's look at what `.bind` does:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (that) { 
  var method = this;
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
  var args = slice.apply(arguments, [1]); // Why is [1] here?
```

`apply` takes the arguments `context, [arg1, arg2, ...]`. So `slice.apply(arguments, [1])` is like calling `arguments.slice(1)`. (As noted in the comments, you could use `call` and drop the array brackets.) The purpose of the `1` is to start the slice from the `1` index. `that` which is passed in is `arguments[0]`. Any arguments passed to `.bind` after the context would be included in this slice. So you might call `myFunc.bind(myContext, arg1, arg2)`; that `slice` would set `args` to `[arg1, arg2]`.

```
  return function () { 
    return method.apply(that, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments, [0]))); // Why is [0] here?
  };
};
```

This is the function that gets returned by `.bind`; this is the function that will actually be called when `myFunc(some, params, here)` is called directly. The `slice` in this case is the entire arguments list; slicing from 0 returns the whole list, converted to an array, so that it can be passed to the outer `apply.`

---

#### TL;DR

The first arguments are sliced from `1` to drop `that` and get all the arguments after it. The second list is sliced from `0` to include ALL the arguments passed in.

Answer (score 0):

### Documentation and Context

Take a closer look at [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), and the [slice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

`apply` takes an object as the context to call a function, with an additional optional parameter of an array of arguments to send to the called function.

#### Slice(0)

`slice(0)` is often used to covert array-like objects into arrays.

`slice.apply(arguments, [0])` is nearly equivalent to arguments.slice(0), except that it will not alter the arguments sent to the main function, but will result in a new array, guaranteed to be an array.

#### Slice(1)

Similar to above, but will remove the first entry from the array.